# Database.SetInitializer from static constructor

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

I want to isolate all of my EF 4.1 implementation in one assembly. The Database.SetInitializer call is usually placed in the Application_Start method of web applications.  Is it safe to call SetInitializer from the static constructor of my DbContext?  It seems to work fine, but I just want to make sure this approach is safe. Static constructors are guaranteed to execute only once per app domain, so there is at least no threading issue. Is there anything else I might need to worry about?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we do the same thing in our own systems.  We have a .Model assembly which encapsulates all of our EF functionality - DbContext, ContextFactory, configurations and the like are all set up there.  Where the initializer is set doesn't really matter as long as it's done first.